# why is there a SIGFPE?

Tags: c, signals, pascals-triangle, sigfpe

for some reason, it used to work. but now i get a SIGFPE.....what's wrong?

```
#include "usefunc.h"

long factorial(long num) {
    if (num > 1) {
        long counter;
        long fact = 1;
        for (counter = num; counter > 0; counter--) fact *= counter;
        return fact;
    }
    else return 0;
}

long combinations(long n, long k) {
    return (factorial(n)) / (factorial(k)*factorial(n-k));
}

int main()
{
    printf("How many rows of Pascal\'s triangle should I print?\t");
    int rows = GetInteger();
    long pArray[rows][rows];
    int counter;
    int counter2;
    for (counter = 1; counter <= rows; counter++)
    {
        int y = rows-counter;
        for (; y > 0; y--) printf("    ");
        for (counter2 = 0; counter2 <= counter; counter2++)
        {
            /*

                    THIS IS AN OUTPUT

            */
            printf("%9.0lu", (long) combinations(counter, counter2));
            pArray[counter][counter2] = (long) combinations(counter, counter2);
        }
        /*

                    THIS IS AN OUTPUT

        */
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your factorial returns 0, which then can cause a divide-by-0 error. shouldn't it be returning 1?

---

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat test.c; make test;./test
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
 return printf("%f\n", 1L / 0);
}
cc     test.c   -o test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:3: warning: division by zero
Floating point exception
```

Comment: A long divided by long is not a floating-point exception.  And a better fix might be to add a check in `combinations` that `k >= 0 && k <= n`.

Comment: This is right — dividing an integer by zero will cause a `SIGFPE`.  Interestingly, dividing a floating point number by zero will not cause a `SIGFPE`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp That's because floating-point arithmetic (which on x86 processors translates to the `divsd` instruction, scalar double-precision divide) is implemented compliant with the IEEE-754 standard, which defines ±nonzero ÷ ±0 as being equal to negative or positive infinity. Accordingly, `printf("%f", -5.0/0.0);` in a C program will typically print "-inf" to stdout. Integer division, OTOH, is implemented using the `idiv` instruction, which is not governed by the rules of IEEE-754. An `idiv` with a `0` denominator is an illegal operation, so it causes a `SIGFPE`.

Comment: @FeRD: Trapping on overflow is also IEEE 754 compliant. The reason why we have the behavior we have, by default, is because some people argued that integer division by zero is likely an error but floating-point division by zero is likely ok. These people “won” the argument, and the name SIGFPE is a historical artifact. (And future architectures seem to be heading towards non-trapping integer division.)

Answer (score 6):

I think it's your `combinations` function, which you haven't shown us, because none of the code you've given uses any floating-point whatsoever.

---

[`SIGFPE` does not mean *floating-point exception*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGFPE), even if that's where the name came from.  @jcomeau has correctly identified why you're getting SIGFPE.

Comment: @tekknolagi: Ok, I don't see any floating-point anywhere.  But you have a bunch of useless casts.  Also your "combinations" function is implemented naively, its internal variables will overflow long before the result does.